# Where do I place mountable Rails engine initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I'd consider myself close to "pro" level for PHP, but this is my first Rails project, and it's a `--mountable` engine at that. That said, I'm trying to gain a grasp of the Ruby/Rails world.

If I have a mounted engine and I want to create global variables (to use inside of the mounted engine). I was advised to place these within the `config/initializers/` directory. However, upon creating the engine it does not create a 'engine/config/initializers/', so should I create that directory, or do I place it in the root application's `config/initializers/` and somehow reference it (e.g., `require`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would just create an initializer file in `config/initialiers`

Comment: Please describe your particulare case. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to create a `root_path` constant for my app/engine to ensure I could always use the exact relative URL path, and I first noticed that `root_path` does not return the same in `.ERb` asset files vs views (e.g., I wanted a dynamic JS file that could AJAX to a relative URL path in case the path changed from various environments, or I changed the engine's mounted URL path, or ended up pulling the engine out and making it its own app). I didn't find anywhere that said I could make an `initializer` within the engine (since engines basically run within the parent app?).